# How to specify a language using Insight API for Twitter from IBM Bluemix Platform

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud

I'm starting to use `Insight API` for Twitter from IBM Bluemix.

It's hard to find supporting resource for using this. So far I am using CURL and specifically formed URL to query the API service, and the service returns results in JSON format.

Here's an example of the URL I used with CURL to search for some tweets with the API:

```
https://(my seucrity key)@cdeservice.mybluemix.net:443/api/v1/messages/search?q=$MSFT%28posted:2016-01-01T00:00:00Z,2016-09-01T00:00:00Z%29&size=20
```

This URL returns a `JSON` object with tweets with keyword #MSFT, and between the time frame of 2016-1-1 to 2016-9-1, only return 20 tweets.

I would like to add to that link by **specifying a language for the tweet** to search for, so far I come up empty. **Can you please help me** ?

I have tried adding the following to the URL and did not do anything:

- lang=EN, lang="en"
- lang:en, lang:EN

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `lang:en` and you need to make sure to include it as part of your query.

I created the following query based on the one you provided in your question:

```
https://username:password@cdeservice.mybluemix.net:443/api/v1/messages/search?q=(%24MSFT%20AND%20posted%3A2016-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%2C2016-09-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%20AND%20lang%3Aen)&size=20
```

The unencoded query is

```
($MSFT AND posted:2016-01-01T00:00:00Z,2016-09-01T00:00:00Z AND lang:en)
```

You can find documentation [here](https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/Twitter/twitter_rest_apis.html#rest_api).

But in this [link](https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/Twitter/twitter_tutorials_samples.html#searching_tweets) you can find more details on the syntax, which is:

```
/api/v1/messages/search?q=QUERY&size=NUMBER&from=NUMBER
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to do the trick. :) Is there an easy way to go from unencoded to encoded URL?

Comment: I used the Insights for Twitter REST API reference here: https://cdeservice.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/rest-api/. Select the messages API, then search, scroll down and enter the unencoded query and click on the "Try it out" button. The encoded URL will be displayed and run. PS: a pop window will be displayed to enter your credentials.

Comment: That's a great resource! I click try it out button and it prompts for authentication. I tried putting my Insight API security user name and password it did not work, and I also tried putting in my bluemix user name and password. It did not work. Do you know what the authentication needs for "https://cdeservice.eu-gb.mybluemix.net"

Comment: Sorry, if you have created your Insights for Twitter in US South you have to use this link: https://cdeservice.mybluemix.net/rest-api/. You have to enter username and password from your Insights for Twitter service credential.